# Get website page html source code in Android

Tags: android

I was trying to get source code of a website and store it in a string in Android, The below code worked well in java, shouldn't the same code work in Android as well. . I checked but the string lies empty

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    URL url=null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://iiitd.ac.in/admission");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try{
        InputStream is = (InputStream) url.getContent();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line = null;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(line);
        }
        String htmlContent = sb.toString();

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText(htmlContent);

        setContentView(textView);
    } 
        catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

textView lies empty
no problem with textView code, it will work fine

Comment: Are you sure you are not getting an exception? And did you give it Internet Permission?

Comment: @Hanlet Escano the code just runs, and displays an empty page!

Comment: It seems this is part of the `onCreate` method. Later Android versions don't allow network access from the UI thread. But the code should have thrown a respective exception.

Comment: @Henry yea I implemented in onCreate, so how how do I access network now?

Comment: @rtmatchbox all network related operation should be done on a thread. use thread or Asynctask

Comment: You should get the input stream, not the content of the url: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html

Comment: @Raghunandan can you little idea where to start, like in different method?

Comment: @rtmatchbox what does this do `url.getContent()`. use `AsyncTask`. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html if you are doing n/w related operation. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

Comment: @Lefteris I was able to get the source code of the url page and store it in a string in java, not in android

Comment: @Raghunandan it streams the entire source code of the url page